# Calling component function throws "is not a function" exception

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a component called `emailValidator` to make a function resuable so that I can use this function on multiple areas of the application. I have imported `emailValidator` into `Contact.js` and called the function like `const email_validator = emailValidator(form)` and passing the form fields values;

***I'm receiving the following error message:***
[image]

***emailValidator.js***

```
export default function emailValidator(form){
    let Response = {status: true, message: ''}
    const namePattern = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;
    const emailPattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
    if(form.name.length < 1 || form.email.length < 1 || form.email.length < 1){
        Response.status = false
        Response.message = 'All the fields are required.'
    } else if(form.name.length < 3){
        Response.status = false
        Response.message = 'The name field cannot be less than 3 characters.'
    }
....
    return Response
}
```

***Contact.js***

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { emailValidator } from '../../components/emailValidator/emailValidator'

export default function Contact() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = {"name": name, "email": email, "message": message}
    const email_validator = emailValidator(form)
    console.log(email_validator)
  }
  return (...);
}
```

Comment: You've exported it as a **default** export, but you're importing it as a **named** import. Remove the curly braces around the import, just `import emailValidator ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `emailValidator.js`, you are exporting `emailValidator` as the default export, but in `Contact.js`, you are importing it as a named import.

To fix this, update your import statement in `Contact.js` from

```
import { emailValidator } from '../../components/emailValidator/emailValidator'
```

to

```
import emailValidator from '../../components/emailValidator/emailValidator'
```

Also, make sure your import path is correct.